# In PyTest, how can I specify a different conftest.py file to use?

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, fixtures, conftest

I'm using Python3.8 with PyTest.  By default, pytest uses

```
./conftest.py
```

to build and import fixtures.  Is it possible to launch pytest and use a different file to load the fixtures -- i.e. specify a different file other than conftest.py?

Comment: This particular name is hardcoded, so no. You can pass a custom module as a plugin though, e.g. rename `conftest.py` to `spam.py` and run `PYTHONPATH=. pytest -p spam`.

Comment: If you were to pass the "-p spam" option, would that override whatever is in the "conftest.py" file?

Comment: No, the `conftest.py` will not be overridden.

Comment: I'm interested in some way to deactivate/activate certain fixtures for different test runs.  If there's a way to control what fixtures are activated through the command line, that would work as well.

Comment: You could implement that logic in fixtures themselves, like `if request.config.getoption('--myflag'): do stuff`. The fixtures will still be loaded and executed, but will do nothing if `--myflag` not provided.

Comment: Renaming that file would be really great as that name is so stupid and confusing :-\